# Google Drive direct download for exe file, I Want the "plugin code" to download a public shared fle

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm making a website and need embedded code for downloading my Google drive files directly. I need an API where I can provide the Google drive File-ID.

https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0By_eomWQaWEob2pvcHB2d1lLU1k

Comment: Off-topic. Looks like search for tools/samples. Accepted answer does not answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the privileges for who can view/access each file/folder by selecting this option

[image]

On the next screen you can select the level of privilege

[image]

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could add your files to Amazon's S3 storage service for client download

Try http://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_l2_sc for an overview, as I believe this would suit your needs more widely. **Without** putting your personal data/storage at risk.